# Translate from visual basic to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do you translate this block of code (on visual basic) to c#

```
For m = 1 To 12
     Dim daysInMonth = curCulture.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, m)
     Dim firstMonthDate = New Date(year, m, 1)
     Dim daysBefore = (7 + (firstMonthDate.DayOfWeek - firstYearDate.DayOfWeek)) Mod 7
     Dim daysBehind = (tblCalendar.Columns.Count - 2) - (daysBefore + daysInMonth) - 1
     Dim monthDays = From d In Enumerable.Range(1, daysInMonth) Select New With {.Day = d.ToString}
     Dim emptyDaysBefore = From d In Enumerable.Range(1, daysBefore) Select New With {.Day = ""}
     Dim emptyDaysAfter = From d In Enumerable.Range(1, daysBehind) Select New With {.Day = ""}
     Dim montos = From d In Enumerable.Range(1, 2) Select New With {.Day = "0"}
     Dim monthName = curCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(m)
     Dim allFields = ({New With {.Day = monthName}}.
                    Union(emptyDaysBefore).
                    Union(monthDays).
                    Union(emptyDaysAfter).
                    Union(montos).
                    Select(Function(d) d.Day)
                    ).ToArray
     tblCalendar.Rows.Add(allFields)
  Next
```

I can't find the union method simply by doing this:

```
for (int _m = 1 ; _m <= 12; _m++) {
     int _daysInMonth = _currentCulture.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(_selYear, _m);
     DateTime _firstMonthDate = new DateTime(_selYear, _m, 1);
     int _daysBefore = (7 + (_firstMonthDate.DayOfWeek - _firstDateOfYear.DayOfWeek)) % 7;
     int _daysBehind = (_tableCalendar.Columns.Count) - (_daysBefore + _daysInMonth) - 1;
     var _monthDays = from d in Enumerable.Range(1, _daysInMonth) select new { Day = d.ToString() };
     var _emptyDaysBefore = from d in Enumerable.Range(1, _daysBefore) select new { Day = "" };
     var _emptyDaysAfter = from d in Enumerable.Range(1, _daysBehind) select new { Day = "" };
     string _monthName = _currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(_m);

     var _allFields = (new { 
               Day = _monthDays
           });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the code:

```
{New With {.Day = monthName}}
```

This is an array in VB.NET - it's a single element array, but still an array. So the corresponding C# code would be:

```
new[] { new { Day = monthName } };
```

The rest of your LINQ expressions should work from there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how effective these tools are as I hardly have to do this sort of thing. But you can give it a try http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: Translation tools like this are rarely successful, and even when they are often produce code that is barely readable.

Comment: I've had pretty decent luck with Telerik's converter - [http://converter.telerik.com/](http://converter.telerik.com/). Not perfect, but seems to be better than most that I've used.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Union in C#. For instance, I can create an anonymous type like this:

```
var anon = new {someString = "S", someInt = someLocalIntValue, myCustomClass = this};
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx

Not entirely sure this is what you're looking for, but I hope this helps.